# I want to add last 30 days sale & 30to 90 days sale with more weightage (1.5) to last 30 day sale

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I want to add last 30 days sale & 30to 90 days sale with more weightage (1.5) to last 30 day sale.

```
SELECT userid, SUM(premiumdetails_netpremium)
from policydetail,
     (SELECT userid AS partner_id, SUM(premiumdetails_netpremium) AS last30sale
      FROM policydetail AS pd
      WHERE DATE(sales_date) BETWEEN current_date - interval '30' day AND current_date
      group by userid
     ) AS A 
WHERE DATE(sales_date) BETWEEN current_date - interval '90' day AND current_date
group by userid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT userid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN sales_date >= current_date - interval '30 day THEN 1.5 * premiumdetails_netpremium
                ELSE premiumdetails_netpremium
           END) as weighted_sum
FROM policydetail
WHERE sales_date >= current_date - interval '90' day 
GROUP BY userid ;
```

Note that this assumes that `sales_date` is not in the future.